# How to change item being hovered and another div at the same time with css

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I've got:

```
<div id="div1"><a href="blah"></a></div>
<div id="div2">Text</div>
```

These two items are layered on top of one another, with div 1 visible. I want on mouse hover for div one, the text in div two to appear over the image in div one AND for div one's opacity to become semi-transparent. Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
#div1:hover {
z-index:1;
opacity:0.2;
}

#div1:hover ~ #div2{
display:block;
z-index:2;
}

#div2:hover ~ #div1{
z-index:1;
opacity:0.2;
display:none;
}

#div2:hover{
display:block;
z-index:2;
}
```

The text is displaying on hover, however, the opacity of the image from div1 doesn't change when I hover.

Comment: Try to create a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ for your example...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript. For example:

```
document.getElementById("div1").on("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("div2").style.opacity = ".5";
});
```

or with JQuery:

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
    $("#div2").style.opacity = ".5";
});
```

Comment: Or in your example, jQuery

Comment: Well yeah, thanks for the clarification. But for me they're nearly synonymous, since I always have JQuery included. I made the corresponding edit to my answer.

Comment: Thats jQuery mixed with pure JS, the jQuery will be `$("#div1").mouseover(function() { $("#div2").css({ opacity: '0.5' }); }).mouseleave(function() { ... });`